# Compiled assembly contains no namespaces

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces, .net-assembly

I have two assemblies: A and B. Assembly B references assembly A. But when I look in the object browser and click on Assembly A, it shows no namespaces.

The target frameworks are both .NET 4.5, the assembly name and the default namespace for A is set properly.

I also tried to have another Assembly C reference Assembly A with the same result, so I figure it must be a problem with Assembly A. It's just a simple class library. Any suggestions?

Comment: Paste a declaration of your most simple class in assembly A. With the header is enough (i.e. `public class...`)

Answer (score 0):

After many frustrating hours, I discovered that my classes were not declared public by default. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...content...
}
```

After changing to

```
public class MyClass
{
    // ...content...
}
```

it worked.

I think Microsoft should make classes public by default. A class that shouldn't be accessed outside should be marked `internal`. But at least I know to check for next time.

Comment: good luck in getting Microsoft to fix the whole compiler tool chain and breaking all code written with it because you can't seam to follow instructions :-)

Comment: What I meant was, I think they should simply type the word "public" or internal in the class template. Don't know why you feel the need to insult people over that...